# Samsung Galaxy S9+ SM-G965F/DS with 120v charger

Tags: lineageos

I purchased a Samsung Galaxy S9+ SM-G965F/DS and noticed that it came with a 230v charger.  I live in the U.S.A., so I need a 120v charger.  Is the SM-G965F/DS model designed only for international usage?  I purchased this particular model because I want to install LineageOS.

Comment: According to [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9+-8967.php), SM-G965F/DS is for Europe/Global dual-SIM, while G965U is for the USA. However, according to [Redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/kmt3pz/problem_installing_lineageos_on_samsung_galaxy_s9/ghgngw7/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), the G965U cannot be unlocked anyway.

Comment: How about buying a 120V-230V converter, too? It will be probably cheaper than buying a completely new charger, although buying only a correct charger had been cheaper. However, you could use these later, for similar problems, too.

Comment: you don't need a ~120 V charger, all mobile phones are charged with =5 V and you can just use any charger with usb 2.0 port. only the cable pin-out is not always identical, i recommend to use samsung usb cable with 200 Ω resistor on data pins to let usb charging protocol allow fast charging https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/177788